# Insert in order a series of bits into a byte (u_int8_t)

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

consider the following variables

```
u_int8_t newData[BITSTREAM_SIZE/BYTE_SIZE];
bool bits[BITSTREAM_SIZE];
```

newData is initialized with zeroes and the array of bits of random ones and zeroes (made as an array of single bits since the stream of bits is dynamic) the bitstream size are equal or greater to multiples of 8.

After some needed calculations with the bitset, i need to convert the array of bits into an array of bytes. For sake of simplicity, i just wish to know what operations are needed to put 8 bits into 1 byte in order (as in most significant bits are place at the beginning and least at the end.)

Comment: Get your sizes right first.  If `BITSTREAM_SIZE` is `7`, you are initializing `u_int8_t newData[0];`  That won't fit.

Comment: the bitstream size are equal or greater to multiples of 8. So i just need to loop a byte 8 times at a time

Comment: `std::bitset<1> bits[BITSTREAM_SIZE];` doesn't make much sense. Do you mean `std::bitset<BITSTREAM_SIZE> bits;`?

Comment: No, bitstream size is dynamic.

Comment: Then you probably want `std::vector<bool>` (for space efficiency) or `std::vector<char>` (for performance) instead. `std::bitset<1>[BITSTREAM_SIZE]` is no more useful than an array of `bool` (and it is also fixed, unless you use VLAs).

Comment: Fine, but either way, i need my question answered please.

Comment: And array of bool will require less space than storing many bitsets inside an array. Keep in mind that those bitsets don't contain one bit but actually 64 bits so they waste 63 bits each. With bool type you only waste 7 bits per bool.

Comment: thanks for the type suggestion, editing the main post

Comment: In almost any use case that an array of bits has, a packed array of bits (ie the result here) can do the same thing better, using the packed nature to operate on multiple bits at once. Now I don't know what exactly the use case is.. but bit streams are generally one of those cases, and not one the exceptions.

Comment: The project I am working on is not mine, so I have to respect the type and size of data the rest of the functions work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// assumes BITSTREAM_SIZE is a multiple of 8
uint8_t newData[BITSTREAM_SIZE/BYTE_SIZE];
bool bits[BITSTREAM_SIZE];

for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < sizeof(newData); ++i)
{
   newData[i] = 0;
   for (size_t j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
       newData[i] = (newData[i] << 1) | (bits[(8 * i) + j] != false);
}
```

Comment: yep, you nailed it! i did not know an OR operator mimics as placing it in order.

Comment: Actually, the order is determined by both the shift operator (multiplies by two) and the or (adds zero or one, depending) .